# How do use database fixtures for production environment

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm wondering how to use `Doctrine` fixtures in a production environment. For example when I want to predefine a fixed set of permissions or a superuser etc.

The [Doctrine documentation states](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html):

> Fixtures are used to load a "fake" set of data into a database that
> can then  be used for testing or to help give you some interesting
> data while you're developing your application.

Therefore I don't want to use the fixtures themselfs because it would be against the concept of it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a great answer to this [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/symfony/comments/3ig9vr/are_you_using_fixtures_in_production_environments/):

> Typically the recommended thing to do is to use migrations. Run the
> fixture code with dump-sql on, and move that into a migration that can
> be consistently deployed in any server.

Comment: I always thought fixtures were generally used in a scenario where you want to have a precise dataaset to run tests off of.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use fixtures with `--append` option, that will not purge database.
[Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#loading-fixtures).

```
php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --append --fixtures=/path/to/production/fixtures1 --fixtures=/path/to/production/fixtures2
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But it's not about purging but about that fixtures just shouldn't be used in prod env.

Comment: @Ron, [citation needed].

Comment: I found a good solution and wanted to share it with the community. Really don't get why you are mad now.

Answer (score 2):

You need just to add this to your command line :

> --env=prod

Comment: Could you link to the doc for further details please?

Comment: `php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --env=prod --append`

If you want add fixtures, you need to set append to keep the old data !